# Partially plugged heater core in my 2013 Toyota tacoma 2.7 L4

Tags: toyota, tacoma, heater-core

The vehicle recently had a blown head gasket. I used bar’s leaks professional head gasket sealer with carbon fiber as a quick and very temporary fix to get me back on the road. The product worked as it should, no problems there. Until the heater basically stopped blowing hot. It will blow relatively hot air but RPM’s have to be above an idle say 1500RPM’s and at the lowest 2 fan speeds. And higher and the air cools off significantly. The vehicle is not running hot. Water pump and clutch fan was replaced at the same time as head gasket. When the vehicle first cranks up after sitting for any length of time. I can audibly hear what sounds to be water flowing into the heater core. Then it stops until it sits. No known leaks, floor boards are dry. I’m only speculating here and my guess is that it’s only partially plugged but plugged nonetheless not allowing ample flow to rid the system of air pockets which could be what I’m hearing when it first cranks up. Any input and ideas are valued and appreciated as to what’s going on and/or how to clean the plugged heater core preferably without removing the dash? Be safe out there.

Comment: Have you tried connecting a tap water hose pipe to the heater core to see if there is a restriction to the flow?

Comment: If the cooling system was flushed after engine repairs, the heater core may be free of sealant but HandyHowie's suggestion to flush the heater core via the two heater hoses disconnected from the engine should reveal any doubt of clogging as water should run free with a garden hose connected to heater core to flow out the other end of the core.  The last step would be correctly burping the cooling system of any air to ensure only coolant circulates.